# How to call multiple functions with one field in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I got two function that are calling same file that user have uploaded, but only first function is executed. How do I make to call both functions? I'm not preforming same things on same file, it is impossible to do this all in one function, I have to do it with multiple functions. Any ideas?

This is views.py

```
def mmy_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            output = io.BytesIO()
            newdoc = request.FILES['docfile']
            dfs = pd.read_excel(newdoc, sheet_name=None, index_col=[0])
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output)
            for name, df in dfs.items():
                #padnas code
                qoutput.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name)

            html = qoutput.to_html()
            writer.save()
            output.seek(0)
            return render(request, 'list.html', {'table': html})
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'list.html', {'form': form})


def mmmy_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()
            return redirect('mmmy-view')
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    context = {'documents': documents, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'list.html', context)
```

Comment: You can try using `signals`, maybe. But these functions seem to be views. Aren't they called upon a request to specific URL?

Comment: They are called when user upload file, but yes, there are individually called by url but on same .html

Answer (score 0):

I guessing that it always calls `mmy_view` function. So you can follow below code snippet:

**Code:**

```
def mmy_view(request):
    ...
    ...
    ...
    # yon can call other function like this before return
    mmmy_view(request)
```

By doing this you face 1 new issue that which `return render(request, 'list.html', {'form': form})` would you use. It will be better to rethink the request flow and construct your functions according that.

> **As I don't have full view of your project structure so I may miss something.**

Comment: it doesn't work, you are right about that new issue. Any idea how to make new flow?